# Typescript files show errors in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea

I am facing issue with TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Earlier I have used IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition for Angular 2 development and it works fine.

This is the error I am getting in my .ts file. Plus there is no intelliSense. Is this feature unavailable in the Community Edition?

[image: CE errors]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript/TypeScript support and many other features [are not available in the Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

[image: ce]

Comment: Yes and No. You are correct that typescript is integrated in IntelliJ Ultimate edition - without the need for plugins. However, in the Community Edition there is also a typescript *plugin* available. It can be downloaded and installed. - That being said, I also get the same issues when I do so. - By the way, this plugin has a website: https://www.sgalinski.de/typo3-produkte-webentwicklung/typoscript-phpstorm-webstorm-intellij/?utm_source=phpstorm&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=typoscript%20plugin&utm_campaign=phpstorm-typoscript

Comment: @bvdb The plugin you mentioned is not for TypeScript, but Typ**o**Script, and it's not a typo :)

Comment: @zhengyue oopz, sorry about that. :-) I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 14):

As zhengyue pointed out in comments, apparently you are using the ["Typ**o**Script" plugin](https://www.sgalinski.de/typo3-produkte-webentwicklung/typoscript-phpstorm-webstorm-intellij/?utm_source=phpstorm&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=typoscript%20plugin&utm_campaign=phpstorm-typoscript), which is not a "Typ**e**script" plugin.

I made the same mistake. And I also had the same problems that you experienced. Personally I thought it was the `@Component` decorator that messed things up. But it was zhengyue who pointed out I was using the wrong plugin.

---

The conclusion for me was that it was better to search for a good alternative. Because I still want to develop my back-end in Java, I wanted ...

- something that **integrates with IntelliJ** as good as possible
- but still something which **is powerful**.

At first I tried eclipse, and found powerful tools in their marketplace, which turned out to be commercial products and expired after 8 days.

Secondly, I downloaded "Visual Studio **Code**", (not to be confused with the full blown Visual Studio). It is FAST and user-friendly. It launches in less than 2 seconds on my system. And it has great plugins, which allow me to use code completion and refacturing tools. Here is the list of plugins I have installed:

[image: plugins]

As you can see, there is a plugin that makes you use the keybindings of intellij.

In IntelliJ I configured my ".ts" files to be handled as javascript files. Because it's better than nothing.

[image: javascript plugin for IntelliJ]

I work in IntelliJ all day when I'm working on the Java back-end, and thanks to the javascript features, I still have some (limited) code highlights for the Angular front-end as well. But, when I want to edit something in the front end, I use Visual Studio Code. To make this a smooth transition, I right-click inside the file and use an external tool configuration:

[image: context menu]

Inside my IntelliJ I configured the root of the angular project as a module. Then the configuration of this external tool looks like this:

[image: configuration of external tool]

This allows me to switch from IntelliJ to Visual Studio code in about 2 seconds, and immediately to the correct line in the correct file.

So, that's what my **free Angular-with-Java-combo development workspace** looks like.

Comment: You're getting maybe a third of what the full support offers you with this, though.

Comment: @Makoto How come, I got everything I want in "Visual Studio Code" ? - including refacturing, - is there anything I don't get ?

Comment: update: all of the above still works, but of course just buying a license for WebStorm would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the plugin TYPO3 Typescript Enterprise 2.6.3.
Which does not work well on Intelli CE.

[image]

[image]

to solve problems you must remove or disable the plugin in the settings.
Open IntelliJ settings and search plugins, then search for plugin TYPO3 Typescript and disable it as on the following image

[image]